# Parsing and Convert Data Type inside Array Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, type-conversion

I have a dynamically generated array that contains string data on each part inside, when I was tried to print it with javascript console.log(res) show like this:

```
[{Activity: "Change Request", Total:"4427" },{ Activity: "Design Escallation", Total:"1067"}]
```

And this my code:

```
this.projectservice.getEventActivity().subscribe((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
})
```

Is there any way to convert and parsing my res into format like this :

```
[["Change Request", 4427],["Design Escallation", 1067]]
```

Thanks for the support guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let data = [{Activity: "Change Request", Total:"4427" },{ Activity: "Design Escallation", Total:"1067"}]

let op = data.map(({ Activity, Total}) => [Activity,Total])

console.log(op)
```

Comment: yeah, and i adding this [Activity,parseInt(Total)]) for make the string number become integer data type

Answer (score 0):

```
this.projectservice.getEventActivity().subscribe((res)=>{
  this.result=res.map(({Activity,Total})=> [Activity,Total])
  console.log(this.result)})
```

without making a mess, this will work!